# Removing specific words present in a numpy array from strings in a dataframe column? [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

> I have a numpy array of words that I want to delete from strings in a Pandas dataframe.
>   For example: If there a word 'the' in that array and there's a string in a column 'The cat'. So it should become ' cat'. I don't want to delete the whole string, just that words.

```
# This will iterate that numpy array
def iterate():
    for x in range(0, 52):
        for y in range(0, 8):
              return (np_array[x,y])

# The code below drops that row/record

filtered = df[~df.content.str.contains(iterate())]
```

> Help will be highly appreciated.

Sample data:
numpy array = [a, about, and, across, after, afterwards, in, on, as]

One sample cell:
df['content'] = Be sure to tune in and watch Donald Trump on Late Night with David Letterman as he presents the Top Ten List tonight!

Sample Output:
Be sure to tune watch Donald Trump Late Night with David Letterman he presents the Top Ten List tonight!

Comment: Hi! To attract people to help you, please share an example data so we can reproduce the problem in our local computers easily. Most of the problems can't be fixed without getting hands dirty.

Comment: @emremrah Thanks, you may have a look now.

Comment: Thanks. First of all, as soon as the iterate function hits the return statement, the function will stop and the for loops won't iterate anymore. I don't think this is the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can manage to get a flat list of stopwords to remove from that Numpy array, you can build a regexp that matches all of the stopwords you want to remove, then use `df.replace`.

```
stopwords = [
    "a", "about", "and", "across", "after",
    "afterwards", "in", "on", "as",
]

# Compile a regular expression that will match all the words in one sweep
stopword_re = re.compile("|".join(r"\b%s\b" % re.escape(word) for word in stopwords))

# Replace and reassign into the column
df["content"].replace(stopword_re, "", inplace=True)
```

You can also add `.replace(re.compile(r"\s+"), " ")` to collapse the resulting multiple spaces into one space, if your application requires that.

Comment: Some words are still there and not removed from the strings, even though their frequencies have been dropped.

Comment: Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 'the' is removed but 'The' isn't, how can I handle this?

Comment: Add `, flags=re.I` to the `re.compile()` call to make it case insensitive.